# C# method name expected

Tags: c#

I just trying to pass some values but it's throwing an error all the time. Can some one correct me what I am missing here?

Am getting error here

```
Thread t_PerthOut = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadCentralOutQueue("test"));
```

I want to pass this string value to `ReadCentralOutQueue`.

```
class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t_PerthOut = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadCentralOutQueue("test"));
            t_PerthOut.Start();

        }



        public void ReadCentralOutQueue(string strQueueName)
        {
            System.Messaging.MessageQueue mq;
            System.Messaging.Message mes;
            string m;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {



                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for " + strQueueName + " Queue.....");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    m = "Exception Occured.";
                    Console.WriteLine(m);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "It's throwing an error" isn't very precise - what's the exception? (It would help if you'd log the actual exception, rather than just using a bare catch block.) Note that the code you've posted isn't even valid - you've given an `else` block with no `if` block.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This code:

```
Thread t_PerthOut = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadCentralOutQueue("test"));
```

tries to call `ReadCentralOutQueue` and *then* create a delegate from the result. That isn't going to work, because it's a void method. Normally you'd use a *method group* to create a delegate, or an *anonymous function* such as a lambda expression. In this case a lambda expression will be easiest:

```
Thread t_PerthOut = new Thread(() => ReadCentralOutQueue("test"));
```

You can't just use `new Thread(ReadCentralOutQueue)` as the `ReadCentralOutQueue` doesn't match the signature for either `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart`.

It's important that you understand *why* you're getting this error, as well as how to fix it.

EDIT: Just to prove it *does* work, here's a short but complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => ReadCentralOutQueue("test"));
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

    }

    public static void ReadCentralOutQueue(string queueName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I would read queue {0} here", queueName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am getting this error even though i followed your instruction "the best overloaded method match for system.threading.thread.thread has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @Usher: You shouldn't... with the lambda expression code that should be fine, unless your method *actually* has a different signature (e.g. it returns a value). Given that the code you've given won't compile, and both methods are instance methods when they should probably be static methods, that may well be the case... giving a short but complete and *accurate* example would really help here. (I've just included a short but complete example which *does* work...)

Comment: It works fine with Lambada exps but am just wondering why this shouldn't work with Thread t_PerthOut = new Thread(ReadCentralOutQueue);
         t_PerthOut.Start("test"); can you please knowledge me

Comment: Thanks a ton Jon,chris and Robert for the timely help.

Comment: @Usher: That doesn't work because the signature for `ReadCentralOutQueue` doesn't match either that of `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart`.

Comment: Hm… But, if that works ­— does anybody needs either of «ThreadStart()» or «ParameterizedThreadStart()» at all? Are here a reason to use it when possible?

Comment: @Hi-Angel: If you're going to call the `Thread` constructor, you'll need one of those two - the lambda expression is just creating a `ThreadStart` here using an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like this:

```
var thread = new Thread(ReadCentralOutQueue);
thread.Start("test");
```

Also `ParameterizedThreadStart` expects a delegate which takes an `object` as parameter so you need to change your signature to this:

```
public static void ReadCentralOutQueue(object state)
{
    var queueName = state as string;

    ...
}
```

Comment: why am getting this error "the best overloaded method match for system.threading.thread.thread has some invalid arguments"

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are not allowed as part of the ThreadStart delegate. There are several other solutions to passing a parameter to a new thread, discussed here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/parameters.shtml

But the one that would probably be simplest in your case is the anonymous method:

```
ThreadStart starter = delegate { Fetch (myUrl); };
new Thread(starter).Start();
```

Comment: is this correct ?  ThreadStart starter = delegate { ReadCentralOutQueue ("myUrl"); };
             new Thread(starter).Start();